# Bing map give me Error Message

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have use bing map in my iOs App displayed correctly but evry time i will get this message.

Invalid Credential sign up for developer account. i used the bing map key.

Please check the attach snapshot.

[image: Error message]

can anybody help me to do this.

Comment: Well, *have* you signed up for a developer account? What code are you using to display the map?

Comment: ya i have alredy register with developer account.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check is your API key is active and correct
2. Check is you have add your API key to the correct plist file. According to the documentation you have to add API key to file named **{appname}_Info.plist**. In my case it was **BingTestApp-Info.plist**
3. Check is an API property named correctly. The name of property have to be **BingMapsKey**. If property name is different the maps will not be working.

I just tried to do everything according to the documentation and it's working fine. This is my screenshot of [plist file](http://s24.postimg.org/xsmyuruth/Screen_Shot_2014_02_12_at_11_39_12_PM.png).